# Sql Server 2008 sp_executesql syntax help - I think my quotes are not correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 I'm trying to build up a string and execute it with sp_executesql. I obviously have some quotes wrong. It appears to run, but the database is not dropped. Can someone help me to correct the syntax?

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name =''@DBName'') 
BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE [@DBName] SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  ALTER DATABASE [@DBName] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  DROP DATABASE [@DBName]
END';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@DBName sysname', @DBName = 'ReapirInformation'

GO
```

I've tried adding and removing quotation marks but I can't seem to dial in the correct mix.  Any tips or tricks are certainly welcome.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: are you getting any errors or is it just failing silently?  Have you tried putting in an ELSE statement, to output something letting you know if it your "EXISTS" if statement is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL does not work like that.
You still cannot pass parameters to a dynamic string that will be used in place of object names.

You have to construct the query string yourself, manually replacing `@DBName` with actual value. However, you can use a parameter on the right side of a equation, without any quotes.

Also, when putting an object name into a query, always use the [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function. It will correctly escape the name so there's no sql injection or unwanted behaviour caused by certain characters in an object's name.

```
SET @sql = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name = @DBName)
BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE ' + quotename(@DBName, '[') + N' SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  ALTER DATABASE ' + quotename(@DBName, '[') + N' SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  DROP DATABASE ' + quotename(@DBName, '[') + N' 
END';
```

Comment: Yes you were correct. Your first solution worked.  I ended up doing this  DECLARE @DBName sysname
SET @DBName = 'RepairInformation'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name = N''' + @DBName + ''')
BEGIN
 ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE [' + @DBName + ']
END'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name =@DBName) 
BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE [@DBName] SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  ALTER DATABASE [@DBName] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  DROP DATABASE [@DBName]
END';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@DBName sysname', @DBName = 'ReapirInformation'

GO
```

Comment: no, this did not work. It parses okay, but it doesn't drop the database.

Comment: @Hcabnettek, are you sure that the DBName is correct. Check 'ReapirInformation'.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've quoted @DBName in the `if exists` query, so it is not going to treat it as a bind variable and thus won't substitute in the name passed in. So the search looking for '@DBName' finds nothing, `if exists` is false and the SQL is done running.
2. Once you fix 1, you've quoted @DBName in the next three lines, so won't substitute the value, and will attempt to Alter @DBName and not the value of @DBName, and attempt to drop @DBName not the value of @DBName.
3. I don't think you can use bind variables for database name, but I might be wrong. If you can't you'll need to build the string dynamically:

   ```
   set @SQL = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name =@DBName)  BEGIN   ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME('ReapirInformation') + N' SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE   ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME('ReapirInformation') + N' SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE   DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME('ReapirInformation') + N' END';
   ```

[OT: Why does stackoverflow lose line breaks when I copy and paste?]

Or something like:

```
SET @sql = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM master.sys.databases sd where name =@DBName)  
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE ##@DBName## SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    ALTER DATABASE ##@DBName## SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE ##@DBName##
END'; 
SET @DBName = N'ReapirInformation';
SET @sql = replace(@sql, N'##@DBNAME##', QUOTENAME(@DBName)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@DBName sysname', @DBName = @DBName
```

Warning untested, no access to SQL Server handy.