# Cannot update SQL table using variable for the table name?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I want to make a stored procedure that i can execute from within c#. I want to update a column but it I need to be able to declare which table i am updating.

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPaddPanelName 
@tableName nvarchar(50),
@panelName nvarchar(10)
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @tableName SET PanelName = @panelName
    END 

GO
```

I am getting the error: "Must declare the table variable "@tableName""

Not sure why this wouldn't work. Seems pretty simple

Comment: See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846743/dynamic-update-statement-with-variable-column-names - you should be able to adjust it for your purposes

Comment: No, object identifiers cannot be variable.  You would need to use dynamic SQL (EXEC/sp_executeSQL) to run the SQL constructed as a string (or not use an SP at all)