# SQL Server Procedure Parameter Using

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I created a procedure successfully but I have an issue on using parameter while executing the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc 
     @table varchar(200)    
AS   
     UPDATE [test].[dbo].[@table]           
     SET [Column 9] = [Column 10]
     WHERE [Column 9] = 'Example1' 
        OR [Column 9] = 'Example2'     
GO
```

When the procedure is executed like this

```
EXEC TestProc @table= '2015-07'
```

I want to update the table `[test].[dbo].[2015-07]`.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: similar problem  [Dynamic update statement with variable column names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12846743/4275342)

Comment: You can't pass the table as a parameter. Using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure doesn't offer any benefits over writing the statement on the client either. In fact, it's *safer* to create a parameterized query on the client and execute it on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I proper urderstood you want to pass name of table to procedure and in procedure update this table. Try to use code below but it will work only for table that have `Column 9` and `Column 10`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc @table varchar(200)    
AS   
DECLARE @SQL varchar(500)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [test].[dbo].[' + @table + ']           
            SET [Column 9]=[Column 10]
            WHERE [Column 9]= ''Example1'' OR [Column 9]=''Example2''' 
EXEC (@SQL) 
GO
```