# Using - select datepart(dw,getdate()) to move a value from one column to another

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is follow-up/revision to a question I had earlier as I believe I was over-thinking.

I have a table set up as the following:

```
ItemNumber
StartTime
EndTime
Price
MonStartTime
MonEndTime
MonPrice
TueStartTime
TueEndTime
TuePrice
```

... and so on for the rest of the week.

Table would look like this

```
ItemNumber StartTime EndTime Price MonStartTime MonEndTime MonPrice .....
1234       1600      1800    2.99  1300         1500       1.89
2345       0900      1100    3.99  1400         2200       2.50
```

I need a script that uses the datepart function to find the day of the week and moves that days Start and End Times and Price to StartTime EndTime Price columns.

In the example above, if Today was Monday, the script would COPY/UPDATE for Item 1234 the MonStartTime of 1300 to the StartTime, the MonEndTime of 1500 to the EndTime and the MonPrice of 1.89 to the Price field.

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Ditch this design. Have one column for DayNumber (1-7), one column for start price and one for end price. The table will have 7 times more rows, but 7 times less columns, and you would insert your datepart() directly.

Comment: Gserg, thanks fro your response...however, ditching the design is not feasible...as our POS software communicates through our webservices to retrieve the StartTime, Endtime and Price from the table.  Secondly, we have a tremendous amount of .net code that communicates with the table.  In addition, there over 1000 stores that utilize the table for price management.

Comment: So ditch this design, redesign the table, and keep sending the data in the old format to all clients (with e.g. a [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) query).

Comment: If you don't like that either, you will have to construct a query dynamically to select [which columns to update](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12846743/11683).

Comment: I figured out the answer to this question!  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
This works!

CREATE procedure p_Calculation_PLUSchedule_Wed

@Store int
, @vYYYYMMDD varchar(8)
, @iCard smallint
AS

/* PLU Schedule Wednesday */

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Client smallint
SET @Client = 1

IF datepart(dw,getdate()) = '4'

BEGIN

Update DatabaseName.dbo.plusschedule
Set price = wedprice, StartTime = WedStartTime, EndTime = WedEndTime
From    DatabaseName.dbo.plusschedule psched
Where   psched.Wednesday = '1'
And     EXISTS (Select *
From DatabaseName.dbo.PlusSchedule D
Where D.Wednesday = '1')

End
GO
```