# Update columns like in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to update multiple columns which have similar names. Is it possible in MySQL?

Something like this:

```
update `my_table` set `column` = 0 where `column` regexp `'Q%[0-9]$'`
```

Comment: It is bad practice to splay data across multiple columns.  It may be better to have another table with the various Q's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You require the use of sys database tables to get the column names so you can set your SQL properly:

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(10)
SET @tableName = 'yourtablenamehere'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = '''' WHERE ' + c.name + ' IS NULL ;'
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types y ON c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = @tableName
and c.name regexp `'Q%[0-9]$'`

EXEC (@sql)
```

reference: [Dynamic update statement with variable column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846743/dynamic-update-statement-with-variable-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update column value based on the column name then you can use wildcard "like". It makes the query more optimized and runs much faster. Something like below should work:

update `my_table` 
set `column` = 0 
where `column` like '%'column_name'%`

Comment: This won't pick based on the column _name_, only on the column _value_.