# Stored procedure update specific column by parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am developing a stored procedure to update specific columns using parameters.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE save_proc
(
   @userid varchar(5),
   @column varchar(10),
   @data varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyProfile 
    SET @column = @data 
    WHERE userid = @userid
```

The following is my code that I've tried but didn't work. Is it possible to do such an update by updating specific columns through parameters? Thanks

Comment: Seems like there's a missing END after BEGIN?

Comment: No, that syntax (a variable instead of a column name) is not valid. Instead, you can use dynamic SQL (building the update statement as a string then executing it). Is this SQL Server, or some other product?

Comment: As Blorgbeard said, you would need to use dynamic SQL (which might have significant disadvantages, especially vulnerability to being hacked). See example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846743/dynamic-update-statement-with-variable-column-names?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: **[`UPDATE tbl SET @colname = @value WHERE keycol = @keyval`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_update)**

Comment: This looks like a poor pattern to be implementing.  If possible you should move this logic into the calling application and have the stored procedure accept the column to update as a parameter.  Doing this kind of meta-pattern in stored procedures tends to result in security and / or performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a query in your stored procedure and execute.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE save_proc
(
   @userid varchar(5),
   @column varchar(10),
   @data varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE MyProfile SET ' + @column + '=''' + @data + ''' WHERE userid = ''' + @userid + ''''
END
```

The method may lead to security concern however.

Comment: What if user wants to insert `NULL` value? `EXEC save_proc '5', 'col', NULL`

Comment: It does not work anyway. You could pass to `EXEC` `value/variable/DEFAULT`  as argument and concatenation is expression.

Answer (score 1):

Its doable but i would avoid doing it.... you code should be like below:

```
DECLARE @column varchar(10)
DECLARE @data varchar(50)
UPDATE DummyTable 
SET 
col1 = CASE WHEN @column = 'Col1' THEN @data ELSE col1 END ,
col2 = CASE WHEN @column = 'Col2' THEN @data ELSE col2 END
where userid =  @userid
.
.
.
```

Hope that this is what you are looking for

Comment: this causes all columns identified to once again be updated; this would invoke a reindexing for some indexes upon columns wherein that change, even if the same value, occurs.  
  
An IF statement is best option for single value, especially if value is NOT the same type as the column datatype.  
  
`BEGIN TRAN  
  
IF(@columnToUpdate == 'columnA') THEN  
UPDATE [myTable] SET @columnToUpdate - @newValue  
  
IF(@columnToUpdate == 'columnA') THEN  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @newValueINT int
UPDATE [myTable] SET @columnToUpdate - @newValue

Answer (score 0):

Using a CASE statement causes all columns identified to once again be updated; this would invoke a reindexing for some indexes upon columns wherein that change, even if the same value, occurs.  Waste of execution updates on server.

An IF statement is best option for single value, especially if value is NOT the same type as the column datatype.

```
IF(@fieldName IS NULL) SELECT @fieldName = ''
IF(@updateValue IS NULL) SELECT @updateValue = ''

DECLARE @myCount int
SELECT @myCount = count(*) FROM [dbo].[myTable] WHERE @inventoryID =  @updateInventoryID

--if no valid data to update,  return -1 for noUpdate
IF(0 = @updateInventoryID 
   OR 0 = @myCount 
   OR '' = @fieldName 
   OR '' = @updateValue)
RETURN -1


BEGIN TRAN

 IF('notes' = @fieldName)  
    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [notes] = @updateValue, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID


 IF('reorderPoint' = @fieldName)  
 BEGIN  
   SET @newValueInt = CONVERT(int, @updateValue)
   UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [reorderPoint] = @newValueInt, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID
 END  


 IF('safetyStock' = @fieldName)  
 BEGIN  
   SET @newValueInt = CONVERT(int, @updateValue)
   UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [safetyStock] = @newValueInt, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID
 END  


 IF('quantityOnHand' = @fieldName)  
 BEGIN  
   SET @newValueInt = CONVERT(int, @updateValue)
   UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [quantityOnHand] = @newValueInt, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID
 END


 IF('totalLeadTimeDays' = @fieldName)  
 BEGIN  
   SET @newValueInt = CONVERT(int, @updateValue)
   UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [totalLeadTimeDays] = @newValueInt, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID
 END

 IF('stockTakeETADate' = @fieldName)  
 BEGIN  
   SET @newValueDatetime = CONVERT(datetime, @updateValue)
   UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] 
    SET [stockTakeETADate] = @newValueDatetime, [modifyDate] = GETDATE() 
    WHERE [inventoryID] = @updateInventoryID
 END

 COMMIT
```

A Try/Catch is advisable