# TSQL trim columns/table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, trim

I am importing to SSMS 2016 txt file (comma delimited, " text qualifier) but within the text there is a lot of " which just causing mess.

So, I have imported this as comma delimited only, with no errors all looks good.
Column(s) look like example:

```
 "Ab-123-2      "
 "wheel 17"    "
 "hello "world"     "
```

Using those to clean this up:

```
 UPDATE table1
 SET    [Column 1] = STUFF([Column 1], 1, 1, '')
 WHERE [Column 1] LIKE '"%'

 UPDATE table1
 SET    [Column 1] = REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE([Column 11]), 1, 1, ''))
 WHERE [Column 1] LIKE '%"'
```

This seems to be working well. Removing first and last " in each row in Column 1

My question is, in this table I have about 40 columns, is the a way to run this against whole table (all columns 1-40) ?

I could do this manually changing everywhere [Column 1] to [Column 2], [column 3] etc.. but takes ages, and I need to repeat this few times in the future.

But would be great to know how to do all this in one hit.

Thanks

Comment: dynamic SQL, where you loop over the column names selected from the table schema, compose a sequence of `UPDATE` statements to a string, then run with `EXECUTE`

Comment: Either what @dlatikay said, or use the table schema to generate a script of 40+ update statements.

Comment: Thanks for lighting fast answers :)  
I am still beginner in TSQL and this script what i posted is  a"remake" of some what i found here.

Not sure what you mean by this, how to write it but looking, googling for this now

Comment: something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12847111/1132334 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12847648/1132334, or a combination of both

Comment: What sort of mess is having `"` in the data causing? If they are meant to be there and you are using the data in, say, an ASP.NET application then they should be dealt with elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After you pull the data into the table you could use this

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Column1,'"',''))),
    Column2 = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Column2,'"',''))),
    ...,
    ColumnN - RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(ColumnN,'"','')))
WHERE...
```

I do realize it is a little more taxing to do it for 40 columns but it is easier than using dynamic SQL and you can just copy paste or do a replace to do it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to Create your UPDATE QUERY like the following:

In this Example i supposed that Table name is `compute_node`

```
        DECLARE @QUERY as VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(50)

        SET @TABLENAME = 'compute_node'
        SET @QUERY =  'UPDATE [' + @TABLENAME + '] SET '

        SELECT @QUERY = @QUERY + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([' + COLUMN_NAME + '],''"'',''''))) ,'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME

        SELECT @QUERY = SUBSTRING(@QUERY, 1 , LEN(@QUERY) - 1 )

        EXEC (@QUERY)
```