# SQL Server: how to replace the line breaks in the text fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE'
  AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

It returns:

```
    COLUMN_NAME
    -------------------
    CiudadConductor
    CiudadPropietario
    CodBaseLegal
    DireccConductor
    DireccPropietario
    PTActa
    PTClase
    PTCodCategoriaClase
    PTCodCIP
    PTCodiConductor
```

With this SQL I need to identify the `varchar` columns that exist, but I want to do a data update.

I know that this SQL replaces but how do I make the two SQL statements work together.

```
REPLACE(ColumnName, CHAR(13),'')
```

I want to remove the line breaks in all `varchar` columns

Comment: If what i understand what I *think* you're after, then you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: yes @Larnu i want remove all line breaks

Comment: Use REPLACE(ColumnName,CHAR(13),'')

Comment: that post could be interesting for your need (espacially @d89761 answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846743/dynamic-update-statement-with-variable-column-names

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server (MSSQL), choose one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (untested), however, the `PRINT` will guide you if it's perhaps a little "off":

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @Table sysname = N'T700InfracTrans';


SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'SET ' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                                   N'    ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N' = REPLACE(REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N',CHAR(13),''''),CHAR(10),'''')'


                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table
                              AND DATA_TYPE = N'varchar'
                            ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
                            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,7,N'') + N';';

PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend.
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to execute
```

Comment: how do I name the table dynamically??

Comment: @BrayanPastor the query is already parametrised. Just change the value of `@Table`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Larnu

Comment: what is it `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,7,N'') + N';'`

Comment: It's creating a "delimited" list of all the columns (the end part, starting with `,1,7...`, is the end of the `STUFF` function). As you didn't tag your SQL Server version I assumed not 2017, however, it is doing the job that `STRING_AGG` would do.

Comment: i have a problem with `@SQL nvarchar(MAX),` my bd exceeds the maximum of varchar characters

Comment: That would (very likely) be impossible, @BrayanPastor. An `nvarchar(MAX)` can store 2GB of characters (which is 1,073,741,824 characters!). War and Peace has 587,287 words, so ever ***if*** they averaged 10 characters a word, you could fit it in an `nvarchar(MAX)` 182 times!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SqlTab TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'TableName'

     INSERT INTO @SqlTab(Sql)
        SELECT
            SQL = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = REPLACE(REPLACE(' + COLUMN_NAME + ', CHAR(13), ''''), CHAR(10), '''') '
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = @TableName --<-- Remove if you want to strip out CRLF in All Tables
            AND DATA_TYPE IN('VARCHAR')
        ORDER BY
            TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME   

     DECLARE @ID INT = -1, @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
     WHILE(1 = 1)
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @ID = ID
                ,@Sql = Sql
            FROM 
                @SqlTab
            WHERE
                ID > @ID

            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
            --PRINT @Sql
            EXEC SP_ExecuteSql @Sql
        END
```

Comment: how do I name the table dynamically??

Comment: @Brayan Pastor I updated the code to allow for a Dynamic Table Name

Comment: @Raymond Nijland - Point taken, I has a snippet file and I forgot to remove the TOP 1 from the snippet

Comment: ok fair enough i will remove that comment, don't forgot mine comment and burn it your brain memory for ever as it is a very common SQL mistake in anny SQL server to make.