# Rename columns from a list of names

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

In SQL Server is there a way to code a rename of all the columns in a table from a comma-separated list of names?

Importing a csv that does not have row headers into a SQL Server table, resulting in columns named:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
```

The column names are in another csv file:

```
date, price, quantity, ...
```

How would I code a rename of all the columns in the imported table with the names from the csv?

Comment: you can generate a list of commands in excel that do something like: `exec sp_rename 'tablename.col1', 'newcol1'` and then run them

Comment: not sure, but I would suggest to import another csv-file to a separate table, e.g. ColumnsNames. Write cursor to read data from this table and in cursor execute sp_rename (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846743/dynamic-update-statement-with-variable-column-names

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Renaming a list of column names can be done by the proc I write for you :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE P_RENAME_LIST_OF_COLUMNS
   @TABLE_SCHEMA sysname = 'dbo',
   @TABLE_NAME sysname,
   @LISTE_OF_ACTUAL_COLUMNS NVARCHAR(max),
   @LISTE_OF_NEW_COLUMNS NVARCHAR(max),
   @SEPARATOR CHAR(1) = ','
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL 
   SET @TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
-- does the tables exists ?
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
              WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND  TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME)
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('table %s.%s does not exists in the database', 16, 1, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME);
   RETURN;
END;

DECLARE @COLS_OLD TABLE (COL_OLD sysname, ORDINAL SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO @COLS_OLD
SELECT TRIM(value), ordinal
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@LISTE_OF_ACTUAL_COLUMNS, @SEPARATOR, 1);
DECLARE @N_OLD SMALLINT;
SELECT @N_OLD = COUNT(*) 
FROM   @COLS_OLD;

DECLARE @COLS_NEW TABLE (COL_NEW sysname, ORDINAL SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO @COLS_NEW
SELECT TRIM(value), ordinal
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@LISTE_OF_NEW_COLUMNS, @SEPARATOR, 1);
DECLARE @N_NEW SMALLINT;
SELECT @N_NEW = COUNT(*) 
FROM   @COLS_NEW;

-- does the number of columns old and new is the same ?
IF @N_OLD <> @N_NEW
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('the number of column''s name in @LISTE_OF_ACTUAL_COLUMNS differs from the number of columns in @LISTE_OF_NEW_COLUMNS', 16, 1);
   RETURN;
END;

-- does all old columns exists ?
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  AS C
                     JOIN @COLS_OLD  AS CO
                        ON C.COLUMN_NAME = CO.COL_OLD 
              WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND  TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
              HAVING COUNT(*) <> @N_OLD)
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('some columns of the @LISTE_OF_ACTUAL_COLUMNS are not in the table %s.%s', 16, 1, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME);
   RETURN;
END; 

-- just do it...
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'EXEC sp_rename N''' +  @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME + '.' + O.COL_OLD + ''', N''' + N.COL_NEW + ''', ''COLUMN'';'
FROM   @COLS_OLD AS O
       JOIN @COLS_NEW AS N   
          ON O.ORDINAL = N.ORDINAL;
EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```

As an example :

```
EXEC P_RENAME_LIST_OF_COLUMNS
   @TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo',
   @TABLE_NAME = 'SQL_Server_Query',
   @LISTE_OF_ACTUAL_COLUMNS = 'PageId, Description',
   @LISTE_OF_NEW_COLUMNS = 'PAGE_ID, DESCRIPTION',
   @SEPARATOR = ','
```